# How to disable dynamic WebAPI for certain application services

Tags: webapi, abp, applicationservice

I want to turn off the automatic WebAPI generation service for a specific application service in my ABP project.

Answer (score 7):

RemoteService attribute can be used to mark a class as a remote service or disable for a particular class that inherently implements the IRemoteService interface

```
[RemoteService(false)]
public class PersonAppService : ApplicationService
{

}
```

if you just want to hide from Swagger

```
[RemoteService(IsMetadataEnabled = false)]
public class PersonAppService : ApplicationService
{

}
```

Comment: nice way of sharing info :-)