# how to stop ABP from querying EMPTY AbpUserOrganizationUnits TABLE

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

We  use ABP with a  MSSQL database hosted on Azure.
in scope of Cost optimization we need to make as less requests to DB as possible.

during investigation i found out that  ABP does  around 50 millions of requests to table  AbpUserOrganizationUnits per month and we don't this table at all
I would like to disable all calls to this table.
making 50 millions requests to database to receive an empty set is not what a normal product should do.

i woudl like to know if there is a way to stop this requests or if redirect them to a redis Cache or even  stop them inside the API

Comment: Can you check your `User.cs` if it has `public List<UserOrganizationUnit> OrganizationUnits { get; set; }`? If so, you can remove it or make it `virtual` so that it will be lazy-loaded.

Comment: You may also check your code, `appServices`, if there are codes that uses `UserOrganizationUnit` and that calls it. Good luck.

Comment: Could you have a look at this answer, please?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66758179/1738819

Comment: ASP.NET Boilerplate or ABP Framework? Why are you tagging two separate frameworks?